# How do I link to the Chrome download page, from a https:// site?

Tags: https

Is there a way on an html page to have a link to the Chrome download page, from a https:// site? I tried using https:// to the Chrome download site, but it just bounces me to Google.

I'm trying to avoid the security warning that IE can throw out.

http://www.google.com/chrome/

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do to stop IE from displaying that message. It's a warning to the user that they are leaving a secure page and going to a non-secure page. That's is something they should be aware of. Fortunately most users choose not to see that message more then once and tell IE not to display after the initial warning. That means the vast majority of your users will never see that warning at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this wasn't an option when you asked this question back in 2011, but you can certainly now link to the *secure* Chrome download page at https://www.google.com/chrome/.